# JK_FF Counter Error with illegal reference

Tags: verilog, counter

I'm making a counter with a JK_FF going 0->1->2->3->4->0

This is my Verilog code:

```
module JK_FF (Q, J, K, clk, rst);
output Q;
input J, K, clk, rst;
reg Q;

always @ (posedge clk or negedge rst)
    if(!rst) Q<=1'b0;
    else 
      case ({J,K})
        2'b00: Q<=Q;
        2'b01: Q<=1'b0;
        2'b10: Q<=1'b0;
        2'b11: Q<=~Q;
      endcase
endmodule

module Counter(A,B,C,JA,KA,JB,KB,JC,KC,clk,rst,in);
output A,B,C;
input JA,KA,JB,KB,JC,KC,clk,rst,in;
reg A,B,C;

JK_FF JKA(A,JA,KA,clk,rst);
JK_FF JKB(B,JB,KB,clk,rst);
JK_FF JKC(C,JC,KC,clk,rst);

always @ (posedge clk or negedge rst)
    if(in==1'b1) begin
        if(!rst) begin
            A<=1'b0;
            B<=1'b0;
            C<=1'b0;
        end
        else begin
            JA<=B&C;
            KA<=1'b1;
            JB<=C;
            KB<=C;
            JC<=~A;
            KC<=1'b1;
        end
    end
endmodule
```

I'm getting an error at

```
            JA<=B&C;
            KA<=1'b1;
            JB<=C;
            KB<=C;
            JC<=~A;
            KC<=1'b1;
```

program says

> Error: C:/Users/hoho/Desktop/project/Counter.v(34): (vlog-2110)
> Illegal reference to net "JA".

How should I fix this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you show is telling you that you must not use an assignment statement to assign a value to a module `input`.

`JA` is a module `input`, and you cannot assign to it like this:

```
JA<=B&C;
```

That is illegal.  The same is true for your other inputs: KA,JB,KB,JC,KC.  You need to redesign your `Counter` module.

---

If you can clear those errors up, you will run into others.  You have multiple drivers for `A`, `B` and `C`.